# SQL Code = -420 Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "decfloat"

Tags: sql, db2

I am having trouble with this code.

```
(SELECT r.SITE_ID, count(distinct r.NIIN)
FROM
(SELECT t.SITE_ID, t.NIIN, B.DT_INVT, B.DT_CRTD,CAST(
case when
B.DT_INVT = '0000000' then B.DT_CRTD + 2000
when B.DT_INVT IS NULL then B.DT_CRTD + 2000
when B.DT_INVT = '       ' then B.DT_CRTD + 2000
ELSE B.DT_INVT + 2000
End as INT) As DueDate
FROM
(SELECT A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN
FROM DDCNENVR.QBO A
WHERE NOT (A.RIC IN ('SMS', 'S9W', 'S9D'))
and A.SITE_ID in ('HECL', 'HECN')
GROUP BY A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN) as t
inner join DDCNENVR.QBS B on t.NIIN = B.NIIN and t.SITE_ID = B.SITE_ID) as r
where r.DueDate between 2018206 and 2019273
GROUP BY r.SITE_ID)
```

The same code works for some dbs but fails in others.

After exporting the data without using the duedate between statement, the column types according to excel are as follows:

B.Dt_inv and B.dt_created are text

Duedate exports as number

Comment: Check https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448700

Comment: And what might the trouble be?  Perhaps you have an error message?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If i run the statement without including the r.DueDate between '2018206' and '2019273' , The code runs smoothly in every environment/db i use. However when adding the previous code, it works smooth for some sites and it gives me a decfloat error for others.

Comment: String concatenation operator in Db2 is `||`, not `+`.

Comment: @mustaccio Please see updated code. the fields are text values that i converted over to INT using the cast function. I still receive the same error.

Comment: You need to share what data types the various columns are, especially any that are going to be implicitly cast to an integer (e.g. `B.DT_INVT`, `DT_CRTD` and `r.DueDate`, and possibly the joined columns if they don't match in data type). Still, my guess is that B.DT_INVT holds values other than `'       '` that can't be cast to a integer (well DECFLOAT).

Comment: @P. Vernon i edited my original question. Im not sure what the data types are being that it is not my db. To my knowledge both dt_invt and Dt_crtd are varchar with values such as 2018102, 2019123 etc etc. the due date is converted to a int when using cast. Is there a statement i can add so that b.dt_invt ignores values that cant be cast into integer?

Comment: What Db2 version are you using? Also, look in the catalog for the datatypes of your columns (e.g. `SYSCAT.COLUMNS`)

Comment: @P.Vernon I will try the syscat.columns when i get to work. The db2 my company currently uses is qmf v11 for websphere

Comment: Use translate function to check for non numeric data in columns DT_INVT and DT_CRTD

example:

trim(translate (B.DT_INVT,' ','0123456789')) <> ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Db2 V11.1.0.0 and above you could use a function such as this to check if a value can be CAST to a DECIMAL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DECIMAL(s VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS SMALLINT
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN 
    REGEXP_LIKE(s, '^\s*[+-]?\s*((\d+\.?\d*)|(\d*\.?\d+))\s*$')
```

Use it like this

```
SELECT DT_INVT FROM DDCNENVR.QBS WHERE IS_DECIMAL(DT_INVT) = 0
```

It is not perfect as it does not allow all formats (e.g. `1e3` is castable to DECIMAL, but this function will say it is not), but it will catch e.g. `12 34` as not castable to DECIMAL whereas the `TRANSLATE` function would not.

It also does not check the length of the string to ensure that it is not more than 31 decimal digits.

Comment: I have tried the IS_DECIMAL statement and it gives me a token error.

Comment: Sorry, I'ld only tested it on Db2 Warehouse.  Try it now with a return type of SMALLINT

Comment: I tried to create the function but im not quite sure where to add it. If it helps i am running IBM QMF.

Comment: If you are using Db2 for z/OS, then I suspect that does not have `REGEXP_LIKE`. Use the TRANSLATE functions that others have suggested

Comment: I decided to just change my Query from Inner to Left JOIN. Solved it. Thank you all for the help.